# How to cast return type of function based on argument type?

Tags: typescript

How can I cast `response.body` to the type of `options.responseType` argument? [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAcwvAZlCI4CIkywKH2ADsYBTKFAQwGMy4B5MGYCYgZzgG9844oy7SBzIAVAJ5gyAfgBc2AEYBXFCgpY4AH2wArdmwIBfQjTbt4CMvAC8cKu3HEacABRKoAG3nmoJBABo4CGZWDjlGELMASjhrAD5uXjgPK35BYXZ6WyoAdypgC2QAOksYN09Anj4+ASEzMUkyeWCWM2ki2oyGqThpaV19YgI+QyikgRh3YjS6kSKFCAATcXxDIA)

The code block bellow is a simplified version of my code... many more options exist.

```js
import got from "got"

interface Options {
  responseType?: "buffer" | "json"
}

const get = async (url: string, options?: Options) => {
  let response = await got.get(url, {
    responseType: options?.responseType ?? "json"
  })
  return response.body
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to use overloads:

```
import got from "got"

interface Options {
  responseType?: "buffer" | "json"
}


async function get (url: string, options: Options & { responseType: "buffer" }) : Promise<Buffer>
async function get(url: string, options: Options & { responseType: "json" }): Promise<object>
async function get(url: string, options?: Options): Promise<unknown>
async function get (url: string, options?: Options) {
  let response = await got.get(url, {
    responseType: options?.responseType
  })
  return response.body
}

let buffer = get("", { responseType: "buffer"})
let object = get("", { responseType: "json" })
let unknown = get("")
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=20&ssc=22&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAcwvAZlCI4CIkywKH2ADsYBTKFAQwGMy4B5MGYCYgZzgG9844oy7SBzIAVAJ5gyAfgBc2AEYBXFCgpY4AH2wArdmwIBfQvirtxxGnBRLLLNojLwAFEqgAbeexhQSCADRwEMysHPJM9hxwAGTc-ILC7GKSZPJYyqrqcIYAlHDyAAroIMBJADwAQipqUAB8puaW1rY0kY4wrh5ePn6BwZHs4SFsnLFc8UIjyVJpegbZOYXFpWRlEAo6ZK31ZhZWNnah7Z2ecN6+xAFBwxxyjDfsi3BFGCtltgDWxBAA7sQ7jX2LTaCCccBO3QuV36oXYdwisLyPD47jBAkmIjgAF44FQflRgPBcAA6UEdNzuQLIvgTRLTVLXAbSYnoukSKS8BacgQwNzEWlTYkKCAAE3E+GM+FR8AyNWxxywWCpApE7IZ6Wq6lyUrB602rXlZOciuVrKmatm+mIGm10rgn2+f0NTmNWByQA)

Comment: Thanks Titian. What if I am using an options argument instead of direct arguments? I simplified my code a lot to make it intelligible, but perhaps it lost its indent. Should I update my question?

Comment: @sunknudsen I think overloads are still your best bet probably with an intersection between the common part and an object type that only contains the responseType (somethign like `CommonSettings & { responseType: "json" }`) If you post the code I can have a look

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Would you mind updating your answer to the updated question?

Comment: Just noticed your example takes for granted `responseType` is set which isn’t the case in the question. What if it doesn’t? TypeScript is throwing a "No overload matches this call." error. See https://lickst.at/eOWJ6EL (TypeScript Playground URL too long for comment).

Answer (score 0):

Use generics T

```
import got from "got";

type ResponseType = "buffer" | "json";

const get = async <T>(url: string, responseType: ResponseType): Promise<T> => {
  let response = await got.get(url, {
    responseType: responseType
  });
  return response.body;
};

get<string>("url", "json");
```